# Xcode Archive failed with flutter plugins

Tags: xcode, flutter

My flutter app run well, but when I try to upload the app to App Store by archive it:
Xcode -> Product -> Archive
it failed and get two errors
First one in flutter_inappwebview with following error message:

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'flutter_inappwebview' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/user1/StudioProjects/app/ios/Pods
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name flutter_inappwebview -O -whole-module-optimization -enforce-exclusivity\=checked @/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/Objects-normal/arm64/flutter_inappwebview.SwiftFileList -D COCOAPODS -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -embed-bitcode -swift-version 5 -I /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview -F /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview -F /Users/user1/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7 -F /Users/osamahhaitham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/OrderedSet -c -num-threads 4 -output-file-map /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/Objects-normal/arm64/flutter_inappwebview-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/Objects-normal/arm64/flutter_inappwebview.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/flutter_inappwebview-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/flutter_inappwebview-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/flutter_inappwebview-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/flutter_inappwebview-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview/include -Xcc -I/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE\=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/Objects-normal/arm64/flutter_inappwebview-Swift.h -import-underlying-module -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml -working-directory /Users/user1/StudioProjects/app/ios/Pods

remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Second issue in DKImagePickerController

```
SwiftCodeGeneration normal arm64 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/user1/StudioProjects/app/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.bc -embed-bitcode -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -O -disable-llvm-optzns -module-name DKImagePickerController -o /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.o

LLVM ERROR: out of memory
Allocation failed
Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.bc -embed-bitcode -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -O -disable-llvm-optzns -module-name DKImagePickerController -o /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.o
1.  Apple Swift version 5.6 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.62 clang-1316.0.20.8)
2.  Compiling with the current language version
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dmjvwbvrfekhkvanzgfshfxgayly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.bc'.
4.  Running pass 'ObjC ARC contraction' on function '@UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM'
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x000000010fa19de7 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 39
1  swift-frontend           0x000000010fa18e38 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 248
2  swift-frontend           0x000000010fa1a440 SignalHandler(int) + 288
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ff81c319dfd _sigtramp + 29
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib   0x00007ff81c137abb _malloc_zone_malloc + 125
5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007ff81c24fd24 abort + 123
6  swift-frontend           0x000000010f966cda llvm::report_bad_alloc_error(char const*, bool) + 106
7  swift-frontend           0x000000010f966cf2 out_of_memory_new_handler() + 18
8  libc++abi.dylib          0x00007ff81c2c196b operator new(unsigned long) + 43
9  swift-frontend           0x000000010f727efd llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments() const + 77
10 swift-frontend           0x000000010d510e87 llvm::objcarc::BundledRetainClaimRVs::insertRVCallWithColors(llvm::Instruction*, llvm::CallBase*, llvm::DenseMap<llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::TinyPtrVector<llvm::BasicBlock*>, llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::BasicBlock*>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::TinyPtrVector<llvm::BasicBlock*> > > const&) + 151
11 swift-frontend           0x000000010d523f88 (anonymous namespace)::ObjCARCContract::run(llvm::Function&, llvm::AAResults*, llvm::DominatorTree*) + 1384
12 swift-frontend           0x000000010f75f380 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 1488
13 swift-frontend           0x000000010f766073 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 67
14 swift-frontend           0x000000010f75fb39 llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 1161
15 swift-frontend           0x000000010ac7d6df swift::performLLVMOptimizations(swift::IRGenOptions const&, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*) + 3791
16 swift-frontend           0x000000010ac7e8cc swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::DiagnosticEngine&, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::StringRef, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 2812
17 swift-frontend           0x000000010ac87aa5 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::ASTContext&, llvm::Module*, llvm::StringRef) + 213
18 swift-frontend           0x000000010a742795 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 16565
19 swift-frontend           0x000000010a7015d4 swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 1108
20 dyld                     0x000000011812c51e start + 462
error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
```

I did pod install & update, did many things but it did not helped
How to fix this problem, thanks

Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: app_test
description: app_test Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 3.5.0+61 

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:  
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13  
  http: ^0.13.4  
  intl: ^0.17.0 
  encrypt: ^5.0.1 
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0 
  searchable_dropdown: ^1.1.3  
  flutter_typeahead: ^3.2.4  
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1  
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+10 
  connectivity_plus: ^2.2.1  
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1  
  file_picker: ^4.5.0 
  open_file: ^3.2.1  
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0  
  path_provider: ^2.0.9 
  sqflite: ^2.0.2 
  device_info_plus: ^3.2.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20 
  maps_launcher: ^2.0.1 
  package_info_plus: ^1.4.0 #package info
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1  #html display
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.4.0+1 #html textbox summernote
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4 # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^19.4.55 
  geolocator: ^8.2.0
  mobile_scanner: ^1.0.0 


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  platform: ^3.1.0
```

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file and your podfile?

Comment: @tomerpacific I updated now with pubspec.yaml file and podfile

Comment: @blue492 Did you update xcode to 13.3?

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes

Comment: @blue492 Then you in luck if it does then that is the segmentation on the packages that needed to be update some packages also abort trap 6 which is needed to update some code so better for now is to go back for 13.2.1 xcode and wait for the author to update the swift file on the package so you have no control on that in some point but to us is wait

Comment: @ArbiterChil how to downgrade xcode to 13.2.1?

Comment: @blue492 download  the 13.2.1 from here https://xcodereleases.com/ and also after expanding click the extracted file. first is goto Xcode->Preferences->location->Command Line Tools select 13.2.1 or just click the eextracted .xip file you downloaded

Comment: @blue492 i edited my new comment

Comment: @ArbiterChil downgrading to 13.2.1 solved my problems, I've spent hours to fix it,
 I wonder how to know if Xcode which makes these issues and not other things?
Thanks for help

Comment: @blue492 no problem glad to help i also encountered that late night last week after updating xcode but damn that thing show up hahaha so thats i have 3 versions og xcode i have in my mac hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downgrading Xcode from 13.3 to 13.2.1 solved my problems.

Comment: Had a similar issue but got the error due to (printing) pub and can also confirm that the downgrade is the proper solution

Comment: Got an "error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')" when building my Flutter app. Downgrading Xcode from 13.3 to 13.2.1  fixed it for me, too.

Answer (score 5):

I added below line in to Podfile in ios folder. I managed to Archive the app and upload to App Store. My Xcode version is 13.3

pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'
end
```

Comment: wow thanks, this was the only reliable and easy solution for me. Totally forgot about the fact, that this solution was a possibility. Thanks!

Comment: just one edit for anyone also following this solution: You also need to then run in the terminal: flutter clean --> pod deintegrate --> flutter pub get --> pod install . Then everything should run perfectly :)

Comment: Yes. you have to run flutter clean and flutter pubget.
The issue is not while running the app on the device but while Archiving.

Comment: Even with Xcode 13.3.1 and Flutter 10.2.4, I still got errors. The above line fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Xcode 13.3 or Swift 5.6 bug happened when you use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`.

Replacing it with `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` resolves this error.

Check more discussions in [[SR-16003]](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-16003) and [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702200).