# Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, flutter

I'm developing IOS app from flutter.
Everything working fine, suddenly I have received error

```
SwiftCodeGeneration normal arm64 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/lasthoney/development_project/flutter/workspace/CTRON/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.bc -embed-bitcode -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -O -disable-llvm-optzns -module-name DKImagePickerController -o /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.o

Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.bc -embed-bitcode -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -O -disable-llvm-optzns -module-name DKImagePickerController -o /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.o
1.  Apple Swift version 5.6 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.62 clang-1316.0.20.8)
2.  Compiling with the current language version
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DKPopoverViewController.bc'.
4.  Running pass 'ObjC ARC contraction' on function '@UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM'
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x0000000107206f88 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 56
1  swift-frontend           0x0000000107205f9c llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 112
2  swift-frontend           0x0000000107207618 SignalHandler(int) + 344
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00000001863b44e4 _sigtramp + 56
4  swift-frontend           0x0000000105184e8c llvm::objcarc::BundledRetainClaimRVs::insertRVCallWithColors(llvm::Instruction*, llvm::CallBase*, llvm::DenseMap<llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::TinyPtrVector<llvm::BasicBlock*>, llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::BasicBlock*>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::TinyPtrVector<llvm::BasicBlock*> > > const&) + 64
5  swift-frontend           0x0000000105195878 (anonymous namespace)::ObjCARCContract::run(llvm::Function&, llvm::AAResults*, llvm::DominatorTree*) + 1024
6  swift-frontend           0x0000000106f7ae24 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 1292
7  swift-frontend           0x0000000106f8138c llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 60
8  swift-frontend           0x0000000106f7b5a8 llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 1088
9  swift-frontend           0x0000000102f46ee8 swift::performLLVMOptimizations(swift::IRGenOptions const&, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*) + 3376
10 swift-frontend           0x0000000102f47e28 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::DiagnosticEngine&, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::StringRef, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 2440
11 swift-frontend           0x0000000102f50364 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::ASTContext&, llvm::Module*, llvm::StringRef) + 180
12 swift-frontend           0x0000000102aa8ea0 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6976
13 swift-frontend           0x0000000102a70130 swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 808
14 dyld                     0x00000001099ad0f4 start + 520
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
```

and also

```
CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/lasthoney/development_project/flutter/workspace/CTRON/ios/Pods
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name DKImagePickerController -O -whole-module-optimization -enforce-exclusivity\=checked @/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DKImagePickerController.SwiftFileList -D COCOAPODS -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk -target armv7-apple-ios9.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -embed-bitcode -swift-version 5 -I /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController -F /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController -F /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DKPhotoGallery -F /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SDWebImage -F /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftyGif -c -num-threads 8 -output-file-map /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DKImagePickerController-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DKImagePickerController.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/DKImagePickerController-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/DKImagePickerController-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/DKImagePickerController-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/DKImagePickerController-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController/include -Xcc -I/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/DerivedSources-normal/armv7 -Xcc -I/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -Xcc -I/Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE\=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DKImagePickerController-Swift.h -import-underlying-module -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/lasthoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ffimvuyezsoasahfibifkngbbnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml -working-directory /Users/lasthoney/development_project/flutter/workspace/CTRON/ios/Pods

remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I searched for this error, but I don't get any solution.

Comment: Did you update xcode to 13.2.1 to 13.3?

Comment: Yes. My Xcode recently updated. Current version 13.3 (13E113)

Comment: The package you've been using is needed to be upgraded for the new swift segmentation code. So the thing is a temporary fix is that go to your build setting find Enabled Bitcode to disable then try it or just go back to 13.2.1 until the packages is updated to its latest swift code requirement.

Comment: Enable Bitcode setting is already No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode Archive failed with flutter plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558250/xcode-archive-failed-with-flutter-plugins)

Answer (score 7):

I added this line in my **Podfile** :

```
pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'
```

As follow :

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'
end
```

And I could *build* my IOS app again by running this command in the ios folder :

```
flutter build ipa
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue with Xcode 13.3 and replaced UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM with UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom

Now able to archive.

Comment: Yes it worked on my M1 Pro...

Comment: please more description where to change ?

Comment: I had the issue on Xcode 13.3.1 (13E500a) and this Cocapods [library](https://github.com/younatics/MediaBrowser) so everywhere where I saw `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` changed to `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` and was able to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change this Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh files to add the -f flag to the call to readlink. In other words, need to replace:

source="$(readlink "${source}")"

with

source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

it's work for me